# How to get a weekly report of changes in Jira

Tags: report, jira

We are using Jira for a Kanban board and our manager wants a weekly report of all the changes in the last week.
Can I generate this from Jira?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple date calculation to retrieve Issues that have been updated in the last week

This will return all issues that were updated since the beginning of the current week.

```
updatedDate > startOfWeek()
```

If you want to see the last 7 days from the current date, use

```
updatedDate > startOfDay(-7d)
```